# configuring asp.net website on iis on windows 7

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

I have website and I configured it on IIS.  I did not supply any ip and let the default be stayed "All unassigned".

When I browse the site from IIS manager it's give error in browser that "The resource cannot be found"  and the url is 'loclhost/MAIN.aspx"

My application name is rentalone but the url does not include the app name. It just gives the page name and localhost.

What am I doing wrong.

Please help 
thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo or not, but `loclhost` is likely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Go into IIS, expand the tree in the left side, you should see a Default Web Site eventually in the tree.  Right click that and select Add Application, it will ask you for a Name and location, location is there you application files are and Name whatever you like.  When that is done, you can go to http://localhost/MyAppName/main.aspx

MyAppName being the name you provided it

Comment: ok it's working now. But the question is what if I need to mention/set ip for the website. In that case I need to add website in site not in default website section of the tree on iis manager. In the case that you mentioned I can't create different application pool. Any solution for that?